# Probability Density Function problem

Tags: probability, probability-theory, functions, probability-distributions

$$ 
f(x) =
\begin{cases}
0  & \text{if $x < 0$} \\
x^2  & \text{if $0 ≤ x < \mu$} \\
α + βx  & \text{if $\mu ≤ x ≤ 10$} \\
0 & \text{if $x ≥ 10$}
\end{cases}
$$

Considering $\Pr(x < µ) = 1/3$. Questions:

- Find $\mu$.
- Find $\alpha$.
- Find $\beta$.
- Find the expected value $E(x)$.

I was solving all questions related to probability density functions with not much difficulty, but this one is driving me nuts. What I have done so far:

$$
\int_{0}^{\mu} x^2 \, dx + \int_{\mu}^{10} (\alpha + \beta x) \, dx = 1
$$

which would lead to something like:

$$
(\frac{x^3}{3} \bigg|_{0} ^{\mu}) + (\alpha \cdot x+ \beta \cdot \frac{x^2}{2}\bigg|_{\mu}^{10}) = 1
$$

Anyone know how to proceed?

Comment: If this was _not_ a problem on probability at all, would $\int_0^\mu x^2\, dx$ equal $\frac{x^3}{3} \int_0^\mu dx$?

Comment: It follows from $$
\int_{0}^{\mu} x^2dx + \int_{\mu}^{10} (\alpha + \beta x)dx = 1
$$

which would lead to something like:

$$
\frac{\mu^3}{3} + \alpha(10 -\mu) + \beta\frac{1}{2}\big( 100 - \mu^2 \big) = 1
$$
while $\mathbb{P}\big( X < \mu \big) = 1/3$ gives us 
$$\int_{0}^{\mu} x^2dx = \frac{\mu^2}{3} = \frac{1}{3} \Rightarrow \mu = 1$$

So we could get a relation between $\alpha$ and $\beta$

$$\alpha + \frac{11}{2}\beta = \frac{2}{27} \,\, . $$  Are you sure that no other conditions is given ?

Comment: Well, it only says that this function is a PDF (Probability Density Function).. nothing more.. This exercise was proposed in an economics master's degree course.

Comment: @Chival "The area under the curve must equal $1$"

Comment: @DilipSarwate, yes, but it is not enough for this question.